Textual guide for IVR (Interactive voice response)
I would love to see a guide to IVRs somewhere. Maybe community-maintained.
I hate waiting for the slow IVR to talk, I get distracted. I would happily read a guide to this in advance,  and key ahead if I could.
Something like
When you call xxxx (eg 03300xxxx)
You will get options Press:
1 for a
a.1 for d
a.2 for e
2 for b
b.1 for f
b.2 for j
b.3 for k
3 for c
c.1 for l
c.2 for m
In the UK, and maybe the US, when you call an 03 or 08 number on an Android phone, it transcribes what is said and lets you press buttons.
If you have seen this "direct my call" robot thing, it would be like that - but community lead maybe. Or a service that you could subscribe to.
The direct my call displays like this when you call HMRC in the UK:

Could be an app.

You may find GetHuman meets some of your wants.  It's been around in one form or another since 2005.  It was originally called the IVR Cheat Sheet.
GetHuman can help you navigate "phone hell", those incredibly annoying and time-wasting voice menus that companies use to save themselves money spent on supporting "valuable" customers (and, according to insiders with whom I have spoken, are sometimes designed to be so cumbersome as to frustrate people, thus reducing call volume).
GetHuman is designed to save you time and frustration.  Ironically, GetHuman's integrated search engine has failed to work for me in quite some time.  Thus, I find the easiest way to use GetHuman is to use your favourite generic search engine and type a company's name followed by a space and then site:gethuman.com.  Most popular search engines support that syntax to search for results within a specific host, or at least within a particular domain.

That is exactly what I wanted! Thanks

@CraigLambie Fantastic! Glad I could help you.
